# Why tension gets lower in rope?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

If we increase the force, F on m1 then the tension gets smaller. I want to visualize why tension is getting smaller without the mathematics .Is there any change in connecting rope which causes change in  tension?

Comment: Yes. Use a more elastic rope.

Answer (score 1):

If your rope is very inelastic then the tension will not get smaller as you increase the force because the block $m_2$ will also take part in the force. But if your rope is elastic like a rubber band  then the tension will get smaller because there is elastic potential energy stored in the band which will use up the force to reform.
Note: I haven't used many terms and mathematics as your request.

Comment: Thanks. It was very helpful!! :D